# Changing the color of points in brackets in a question with documentclass "exam"

Tags: color, exam, points

I'm quite new to LaTex and I do try to write an exam with the doumentclass "exam". Everything is good so far but now I want to have the given points of questions to appear in a different color than the rest of the text. Is there any way to do this with something like "renewcommand" ... but which command should be renewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `\pointformat` to change how points are printed. For example,

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \pointformat{(\textcolor{red}{\thepoints})}
    \question[10] A question.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are much more details and many examples in `exam`'s [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam).